# Как сделать вертикальный скролл модального окна?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Есть следующее модальное окно:

```css
.cart-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 29;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}

.cart {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 1100px;
  padding: 35px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 700px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cart__info {
  margin-top: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-container">
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="cart__header">Оформление заказа</div>
    <div class="cart__product">Продукт</div>
    <div class="cart__upsales">Апсейлс</div>
    <div class="cart__info">Инфо</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но у него почему-то не работает вертикальный скролл, хотя его размер больше, чем размер экрана. Каким образом правильно делать вертикальный скролл у модального окна?

CP: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/WyEaQe

Comment: Мб., `max-height`?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте `overlay` отдельным блоком и задайте ему стили `cart-container`.
Это самый простой пример. Если хотите более бодробно изучить, просмотри код уже готовых плагинов(Magnific и тп).

```css
.g-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 29;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  //overflow: hidden;
}

.cart {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  margin: 30px auto;
  //height: 1100px;
  padding: 35px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 700px;
  //overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.cart__info {
  margin-top: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="g-overlay"></div>
<div class="cart-container">
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="cart__header">Оформление заказа</div>
    <div class="cart__product">Продукт</div>
    <div class="cart__upsales">Апсейлс</div>
    <div class="cart__info">Инфо</div>
  </div>
</div>
```